# Cut a variable from another variable python BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

```
var1 = '475 Amsterdam AveNew York, NY 10024'
var2 = '475 Amsterdam Ave'
```

I want to get `"New York, NY 10024"` from var1

I tried:

```
var3 = var1 - var2
print(var3)
```

But it is not working.

Can anyone help me with this? Thanks.

Comment: Use `replace` to "cut" a string from another string: `var1.replace(var2, '')`

Comment: That's going to work fine unless the string to replace is found more than once. Then it depends on what the author expects to happen

Comment: Thanks, @Iain Shelvington, good solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use either `find()` with string `slicing` or `replace()` as pointed by Iain based on your requirements:

Scenario 1: When `var1` contains a single occurrence of `var2`:

Implementation with both `find()` with `slicing` and `replace()`:

```
var1 = '475 Amsterdam AveNew York, NY 10024'
var2 = '475 Amsterdam Ave'

idx = var1.find(var2)
res = var1[idx+len(var2):] if idx >= 0 else var1
print(res)

res = var1.replace(var2, '')
print(res)
```

Output: Here both produce produce the same output

```
New York, NY 10024
New York, NY 10024
```

Scenario 2: When `var2` contains multiple occurrences of `var1`:

Implementation with both `find()` with `slicing` and `replace()`:

```
var1 = '475 Amsterdam AveNew York, NY 10024 475 Amsterdam Ave' # note that var1 has two occurrences of var2
var2 = '475 Amsterdam Ave'

idx = var1.find(var2)
res = var1[idx+len(var2):] if idx >= 0 else var1
print(res)

res = var1.replace(var2, '')
print(res)
```

Output: Here both produce a different object

```
New York, NY 10024 475 Amsterdam Ave
New York, NY 10024
```

Based on the above examples, you could use either of `find()` with `slicing` or `replace()` based on your output requirements.